# How to show-or-hide image loader in the row that button clicked on it in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a grid view with update panel and I set an image loader when the post back occur, But when I click on one button in for example row 5, all of loader display inline,but i just need to show the exactly image loader near my button that i click on it,How can I do that in j query or java script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                   var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                                   prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
                                   prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

                                   function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                                       //$(".load").show();
                                       $('.btn').live("click", function () {
                                           //$('tr [type="checkbox"]:checked').parent().parent().each(function () {
                                               //if ($(this).find('input[id*="txtSalaryHead"]').length > 0) {
                                                   //alert($(this).find('input[id*="txtSalaryHead"]').val() + "---" + $(this).find('input[id*="hdnHeadId"]').val())
                                               //}
                                           $(".load").show();
                                           });

                                       //});
                                   }

                                   function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                                       $(".load").hide();

                                   }
                               </script>
```

and this my code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl1">
                               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                                   <ContentTemplate>


                                        &nbsp;
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#D53B22"
                                           Text="تعداد : " Width="42px"></asp:Label>
                                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_no" runat="server" CssClass="ddlno">
                                           <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem Value="10"></asp:ListItem>

                                       </asp:DropDownList>
                                       &nbsp;
                                        <asp:Button ID="btn_addBasket" runat="server" CssClass="btn"  Text="اضافه به سبد"  OnClick="btn_addBasket_Click" />

                                       <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="load" style="display:none;"/>
                                   </ContentTemplate>
                               </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                               <script type="text/javascript">
                                   var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                                   prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
                                   prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

                                   function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                                       //$(".load").show();
                                       $('.btn').live("click", function () {
                                           //$('tr [type="checkbox"]:checked').parent().parent().each(function () {
                                               //if ($(this).find('input[id*="txtSalaryHead"]').length > 0) {
                                                   //alert($(this).find('input[id*="txtSalaryHead"]').val() + "---" + $(this).find('input[id*="hdnHeadId"]').val())
                                               //}
                                           $(".load").show();
                                           });

                                       //});
                                   }

                                   function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                                       $(".load").hide();

                                   }
                               </script>
                           </asp:Panel>
```

this code in my grid view template and i want show img with id=loader when my button(id=btn_addbasket) click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be more specific without seeing your markup, but in general it looks like something like this is happening:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span class="load">something</span>
        <button class="btn">click here</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="load">something</span>
        <button class="btn">click here</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="load">something</span>
        <button class="btn">click here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in your JavaScript code, when you reference `$('.load')`, you're referencing *every* element with that class.  But you only want to reference the nearest element to the button that was clicked.  Perhaps instead of this:

```
$(".load").show();
```

Try something more like this:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.load').show();
```

Again, without seeing your markup, I can't be specific.  This is a general concept, not code to be copied/pasted to solve your problem.  But what this is essentially doing is:

1. Referencing the button which was clicked: `$(this)`
2. Referencing the parent `div` (or whatever element you use) to that button: `$(this).closest('div')`
3. Referencing children of that parent with the class `load`: `$(this).closest('div').find('.load')`

This way only the elements of class `load` which share that common parent element with the specific button (I'm guessing there should be only one for each button) are referenced when calling `show()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i put my code there but i cant show the image

Comment: @hony: That's your server-side code, not your client-side markup that ends up in the browser.  JavaScript is only going to see the resulting client-side markup, so you need to know that markup in order to interact with it.